# About UUID data type as Primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, uuid

By using `UUID` as a primary key in a table we can protect our data from attackers, But we also store the `user ID` kind of details in the table. If the hacker gets to know the User ID he can get to know details about the row. So, What's the use of `UUID` here?

Comment: Hey, I do not understand what you mean with UUID as a primary key being able to protect data? It is just what the name says, a universally unique identifier. It does not have any protective measures. Maybe you can edit your question and elaborate on what you mean?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UUID` is basically there for uniquely identify records in the table. There's nothing related to security. What you need prevent is `SQL injection` attacks from happenning to your database. For that you can use `Parameterized stored procedures`. Either case once the intruder has access to the database it means either way he will have the access to the table rows.

Answer (score 0):

For internal relations and for referencing, an integer with auto increment is perfect: small size and small index.

I use additionally UUID in some projects to hide data uploaded/set by a user. The user gets a link with UUID and can provide it to any other. Example for a database layout for this case:

```
dis_id  int unsigned not NULL auto_increment,
uuid    char(36) not NULL COLLATE latin1_bin,
```

... and optional ...

```
unique key(uuid)
```

Collation `latin1_bin` optimizes space and search efficiency. You can store an UUID as 16 byte binary data too.